# userId.getUserById is not a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs

When a user click's on a username on the list below, it's meant to open up the add user page with the name's of the user in the fields.

[image]

I get this error message:

[image]

Here's the code in the manage users page:

```
    componentWillMount: function () {
    var userId = this.props.params.id; // from the path /user:id

    if (userId) {
        this.setState({ user: userId.getUserById(userId) });
    }
},
```

Here's the code in the userApi:

```
    getUserById: function(id) {
    var user = _.find(users, {id: id});
    return _clone(user);
},
```

I am new to StackOverflow and programming, so if this post doesn't meet the community's guidelines, please guide me on how to better make use this platform so I can further my learning progression.

Thanks,

Rickie

Comment: So how does `this.props.params.id;` relate to `userId.getUserById(userId)`.... My guess is you have some library code and than you used the same variable name and expect it to be able to tell the difference or copy and paste error?

Comment: I think you might be making a simple mistake here, don't you want something like: this.setState({ user: userApi.getUserById(userId) }); NOTE The userApi as opposed to userId

Comment: I can't give you an answer with the code you've posted. But I think you want to call something like `userApi.getUserById` and not `userId.gerUserById`

Comment: @janusPienaar - that worked. I can't quite work out how I made that mistake. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the **userId** variable you can't call your API. Since **getUserById** is from your API you must call the method from there.

```
userApi.getUserById(userId);
```